# Multidimensional Array given the dimensions

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

How can I make an array given the dimensions introduced by user??

For example, if you introduced 5(the dimensions) inside of that array we need an array of 4 dimensions, inside of it 3 dimensions and etc...

Please help!

Comment: Could you be a bit more clear? Sorry but I cannot understand what you are saying.

Comment: give an example of what you expecting.

Comment: I meant, if i give 5 as a parameter indicating the dimensions of the array, how can i make it from that? Just giving the number of the dimensions

Comment: @Silmar Java requires the arity of an array to be fixed in the source code, one could use reflection, nesting of objects or managing the layout of an array by hand.. however this feels like a strange request.  What has lead you to having this need?

Comment: No, we don't need the arity of an array to be fixed.  We can just use `Object[]` over and over - have a loop that nests one `Object[]` in another.  But, yes, the big question is WHY!

Comment: Can't a list be used?

Comment: @WannaBeCoder yes lists could be used; that would be another example of nesting objects

Comment: There becomes a point where nesting objects to create multi dimensional arrays starts to feel like a tree ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Array#newInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance-java.lang.Class-int...-)

```
int[][][] ar = (int[][][]) Array.newInstance(int.class, 3, 2, 1);
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(ar));
```

or

```
int[] dimensionLengths = new int[numberOfDimensions];
Arrays.fill(dimensionLengths, 1);
Array.newInstance(int.class, dimensionLengths);
```

Comment: I guess the OP wants to create an array with out knowing the dimensions in compile time.

Comment: `numberOfDimensions` in my second example does not need to be known at compile time

Comment: I just re-read your answer.  Sorry for my earlier comment.  This is a very good idea.  In your second example though, you need to populate that `int[numberOfDimensions]` with something before you pass it to `newInstance`.  Like all ones or something.  Anyway, +1 for a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

Since an array is an Object, an array of Object (Object[]) can itself hold arrays, and so on.
This would require a lot of castings, and would be very un-type-safe and ugly, but it can be done.

For example :

```
 Object[] arr3d = new Object[10];          // create the first dimension
 arr3d[0] = new Object[20];                // create the second dimension
 ((Object[])arr3d[0])[0] = new Object[30]; // create the third dimension
 ...
```

I wouldn't recommend actually doing it, though.

Comment: You'd have to do that in a loop to fulfil the requirements of the question.